# Import datetime field correctly into mysql table using load data infile

Tags: mysql

I'm facing problem for `datetime` fields while importing file using **mysql** command `load data local infile`, but if I import the same file using `Table Data Import Wizard`  in **MySQL Workbench** it works perfectly. But this option is extremely slow. It's been more than 2 hrs only 10% data imported for only 12k data sample. As I found out that `load data local infile` command is much faster, I'm going for it but stuck currently for `datetime` field.

**Sample data file content:** *(Last 2 fields are `created_at` and `updated_at` fields which are having problem while importing)*

```
740c02a0-54d9-11eb-b1aa-1312597791fc,RAMKKUMAR,Test@GMAIL.COM,2018-16-05 21:05:00,2018-22-11 4:47:00
```

**Sample Code:**

```
load data local infile 'C:/Newwamp64/bin/mysql/mysql5.7.26/bin/for.csv' 
    into table mytable.users 
    FIELDS OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'  
    TERMINATED BY ',' 
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' 
    IGNORE 1 LINES 
        SET created_at = STR_TO_DATE(@created_at, '%Y-%d-%m %H:%i:%s');
```

**Result**
All fileds are fine, except following two -

`created_at` -> NULL

`updated_at` -> 0000-00-00 00:00:00

Comment: Are you sure your .csv file is well-formed? It looks like you have a space at the end of some fields. Also, your `created_at` and `updated_at` values in your .csv example should be loadable without the use of `STR_TO_DATE()`, they're the format MySQL uses to represent dates with strings.

Comment: @O.Jones sorry for those spacings. It's well formatted in actual file(generated using MS Excel) without any spacing for particular row and with first line as column names. I have modified here because it had lot of extra fields..

Comment: and yes `STR_TO_DATE` should not be required but `updated_at` field has all zero values `0000-00-00 00:00:00`.

Comment: You can clear the [so-called `NO_ZERO_DATE` mode](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_no_zero_date) in MySQL before you do your load. Then it will accept those dates.